# Are links being inappropriately stripped of characters?

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, design

I recently tried to answer a post by including a link to Wolfram Alpha, and the link contained various mathematical characters.  I posted it and noticed that, when clicked, something was not formatted correctly and it took me to a different page in Wolfram Alpha.  Is there a problem with certain characters in hyperlinks?

I'm not sure if this will come out correctly, but I tried this:

`http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize+f%28x%2Cy%29+%3D+%28x-4%29^2+%2B+%28y-6%29^2+subject+to+12+%3E%3D+x+%2B+y%2C+x+%3E%3D+6%2C+y%3E%3D+0+`

and got this:

`http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize+f%28x,y%29+=+%28x-4%29%5E2+++%28y-6%29%5E2+subject+to+12+%3E=+x+++y,+x+%3E=+6,+y%3E=+0+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we were indeed not handling plus signs in the URLs correctly ([these have different semantics depending on where they appear in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678551/when-to-encode-space-to-plus-and-when-to-20/2678602#2678602)). This will be fixed in the next build.

Answer (score 3):

I verified that

`http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize+f%28x%2Cy%29+%3D+%28x-4%29^2+%2B+%28y-6%29^2+subject+to+12+%3E%3D+x+%2B+y%2C+x+%3E%3D+6%2C+y%3E%3D+0+`

is a valid link in my browser.

I pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to enter a link, then pasted it in and got

[the following link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize+f%28x,y%29+=+%28x-4%29%5E2+++%28y-6%29%5E2+subject+to+12+%3E=+x+++y,+x+%3E=+6,+y%3E=+0+)

Which does produce different results, as you noted. We'll take a look at it.